# dynamic max-height with js in firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, prototypejs, prototype

I cannot alter the max-height value of a div in javascript.  Can anyone give me any hints.  It works in chrome, safari, and IE but not in firefox.  Is there any way to get it to work in FF?

http://jsfiddle.net/4k7Rk/

```
<div id='box'>
    lot of text<br/>
    lot of text<br/>
</div>

#box {
    max-height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
$('box').setStyle({'max-height': '100px'})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PrototypeJS documentation you need to use the Camelized version of the style

So instead of

```
$('box').setStyle({'max-height': '100px'});
```

It should be

```
$('box').setStyle({'maxHeight': '100px'});
```

This fiddle shows it working in Firefox 20 http://jsfiddle.net/4k7Rk/6/

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/setStyle/

Comment: Exactly. Additionally you do not need the `''` in the object property name:
`$('box').setStyle({ maxHeight: '100px' });`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$('#box').css('max-height', '100px');
```

Without jQuery

```
document.getElementById('box').style.maxHeight = '100px';
```

See this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/bd8t9/1/

Comment: I can not use jQuery unfortunately.  It appears that this might be a prototype problem, all of the other styles can be changed using setStyle() but max-height does not budge for some reason.

Comment: I've added a non-jQuery way of solving this and a working fiddle.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I am not sure why prototype is not working but I guess I will have to fall back to pure JS.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the overflow is set to hidden.

```
$('#box').css({'max-height':'100px','overflow':'auto'});
```